# Reddit like comment section - MongoDB

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongodb-query, reddit

What is the best way of building a reddit like comment section using MongoDB? Is it possible to search deeply nested objects directly by their references or ObjectIds?

I'm trying to avoid iterative solutions. An Ideal solution would be some sort of a linkedlist implementation where I can pass a reference of a parent "comment" from the client side then directly access its children.

For example:

```
Comments: {
 _id: ObjectId(4564684),
 comment: 'comment',
 children: children: children..: (either another document or array based on performance and
            ability to sort based on child value such as number of upvotes. Need
            answer for this as well)
}
```

Comment: "Is it possible to search deeply nested objects directly by their references or ObjectIds?" - no.

Comment: If I were to do this, I'd try to severely limit embedding. For example, don't embed at all and have each comment be their own document which stores either a list of parents (up to root) or ids of immediate children. Or maybe both.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Thank you. I like your idea of keeping each comment in a separate document and include ids of their parents.